# IF..ELSE statement in simple SQL SELECT queries

Tags: mysql, if-statement

I have 2 tables tmp1 and tmp2. They looks like below:

tmp1:

```
+----+------+---------+---------+
| id | name | add1    | add2    |
+----+------+---------+---------+
| 1  | NULL | NULL    | NULL    |
| 2  | NULL | NULL    | NULL    |
| 3  | mum1 | rajpur1 | rajpur2 |
| 4  | mum3 | rajpur3 | rajpur4 |
+----+------+---------+---------+
```

tmp2:

```
+----+------+---------+---------+
| id | name | add1    | add2    |
+----+------+---------+---------+
| 1  | NULL | NULL    | NULL    |
| 2  | mum  | rajpur  | rajpur1 |
| 3  | NULL | NULL    | NULL    |
| 4  | mum2 | rajpur2 | rajpur3 |
+----+------+---------+---------+
```

I want to use if..else statement here to retrieve some data like:

```
Case 1: if id=1 then (select * from tmp1 where id=1)

Case 2: if id=2 then (select * from tmp2 where id=2)

Case 3: if id=3 then (select * from tmp1 where id=3)

Case 4: if id=4 then (select * from tmp1 where id=4)
```

I'm trying to solve this question from last 2 days. pls help it's really important.

Comment: What do you mean with "if id=1"? Do you mean to select from a different table according to the value of id in the where condition?

Comment: update  your question and add  the code you are using ..  and based on your date sample .. show us also you expected  result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following query is what you actually want to achieve:

```
select 
 tmp1.id id, 
 coalesce(tmp1.name,tmp2.name) name,
 coalesce(tmp1.add1,tmp2.add1) add1,
 coalesce(tmp1.add2,tmp2.add2) add2 
from 
 tmp1 inner join tmp2 on tmp1.id=tmp2.id;
```

Result:

```
+------+------+---------+---------+
| id   | name | add1    | add2    |
+------+------+---------+---------+
|    1 | NULL | NULL    | NULL    |
|    2 | mum  | rapjur  | rapjur1 |
|    3 | mum1 | rajpur1 | rajpur2 |
|    4 | mum3 | rajpur3 | rajpur4 |
+------+------+---------+---------+
```

[info on coalesce](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-coalesce/)

Answer (score 0):

This try to select first not null values for each id.

```
SELECT t1.id 
     , COALESCE (t1.name, t2.name) as name
     , COALESCE (t1.add1, t2.add1) as add1
     , COALESCE (t1.add2, t2.add2) as add2
FROM t1
JOIN t2
  ON t1.id = t2.id
```